# How to create Chained JOIN query in RAILS to generate excel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using to_xls gem to generate excel sheets.
My query requires to Fetch data from bill model, property model, owner model and bank details model wherein all the models above form a chain.

My associations are as follows.

Bill model

```
   belongs_to   :property,  class_name: "::Property"
```

Property model

```
   has_many :owners,    class_name: "::Properties::Owner"
   has_many :bills,     class_name: "::Bill"
```

Property::Owner

```
   belongs_to   :property,  class_name: "::Property"
   has_one  :bank_detail, as: :account, class_name: "::Users::BankDetail"
```

Users::BankDetail

```
   belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
```

My query has to contain bill.amount, bill.property.owners.(each owner)name ( property can have many owners), bill.property.owners.(each owner)email, bill.property.owners.(each owner)mobile, and bill.property.owners.(on each owner).bank_detail.ifsc.

In my Bills controller

```
    def create_excel 
    @bills = Bill.all
    respond_to do |format|  
    format.html
    format.xls do
     send_data( 
              Bill.all.joins(property: {owners: :bank_detail}).select('
     bills.amount, bills.created_at, owners.name as owners_name').to_xls,
      content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
      filename: 'excel.xls')
   end
   end  
   end
```

Here, however, it throws an error on

```
   ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "owners"
   LINE 1: SELECT  bills.amount, bills.created_at, owners.name as 
   owner_name...
```

I am very unsure how to write this SQL query in rails since I am a beginner. Can someone plz help me with the exact query to display on to my excel sheet.Plz, help!

Comment: what if you remove `.all`?

Comment: doesn't do anything, throws the same errors.

Comment: try this in your `bill.rb` after `belongs_to`, `has_many :owners, through: :property`